# Inner Join or UNION

Tags: sql-server

For ID =101 Data is coming from different TABLE

All the TABLES have a ID column

```
           Name      Income     
Table_A     a        $6,868     
Table_B     b        $4,443 
Table_C     c        $6,726     
Table_D     d        $10,163    
Table_E     e        $4,853 
Table_F     f        $3,368
```

To get result like above Should I use UNION or Inner JOIN ?

```
TABLE_A

ID  NAME  INCOME
101  a    $6,868    


TABLE_B

ID  NAME  INCOME
101  b    $4,443
```

like that other table

so should I use Inner Join or UNION here ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to even understand what you're asking about, let alone answer it!

Comment: Could you give the structure of your tables?

Comment: It looks like your design structure is off a bit.  Table_A should be ID (Auto Increment), OtherID(101 in this case), Name, Income.

Comment: @Widor above result could be achieved by inner join or union so my question is about performance if number of rows are more and same id is present in different TABLE

Comment: @tsells I have just given  a scenario and there are more ID'd present in TABLE with Autoincrement

Comment: @Fred TABLE_A and TABLE_B is given .. similar structure is for other TABLE and there are millions of rows like that so I was thinking to improve performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If row `X` is computed by looking *only* at table `X`, then `UNION` is the correct tool to use.

Comment: Would you do a WHERE ID=101 on each SELECT?  SELECT a.Income FROM Table_A a WHERE a.ID=101 UNION ...  ?  Or will SQL optimize it even with a single WHERE at the end?

Comment: @mikey: I'd do multiple `SELECT ... WHERE` and then `UNION` them together.

Comment: Right on, thanks, I'd imagine the performance would be roughly comparable to the inner join approach?

Comment: @mikey: It certainly wouldn't be slower, and there's absolutely no reason to use an `INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: Easier to read, I myself am guilty of using joins for just about everything which is why I was so curious ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd way to have a database design, but you would use an `INNER JOIN` for this sort of query.

Something like:

```
select *
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on a.ID = b.ID
inner join table_c c
on a.ID = c.ID
inner join table_d d
on a.ID = d.ID
inner join table_e e
on a.ID = e.ID
inner join table_f f
on a.ID = f.ID
where a.ID = 101
```

Without knowing more about the structure of your existing tables, it is hard to give a more specific query for your utilization.